# Failed to execute hdfs -ls command on hadoop 2.8

Tags: hadoop2

hdfs -ls command is not working but Hadoop **fs -ls** is working fine, I got the following error when use

```
hdfs -ls.
```

> Unrecognized option: -ls Error: Could not create the Java Virtual
>   Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. The program will exit.

could you please help, I am new to Hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

hadoop is a user group,but hdfs is an user name.
so you can use hdfs dfs -ls.dfs means (distributed file system)it will works fine.